# 415 Unsupported Media Type (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to WebServices. I am working on an application where I am using AnhularJs1.x at client side which sends data to Spring Rest Controller.

The architecture of the application is micro-services based. I am able to receive the data from angular to Front end Rest Controller which are in the same war.

From this controller I am calling a service which internally calls another micro-service which interacts with database.

When I am sending the data received in my front end controller to another micro-service I get **415 Unsupported Media Type (org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException)**

Below is my front end controller which is in the same war as angularJS

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/servicearticles",  method = RequestMethod.POST,        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle> saveData(@RequestBody      List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticleList){
    System.out.println("In savedata");
    System.out.println(serviceArticleList.toString());


    try {
        if(null != serviceArticleList && serviceArticleList.size() >0){
            serviceArticleAdminService.insertData(serviceArticleList);
        }else{
            logger.error("File is empty. No data to save");
        }
```

I am able to get data in this contoller :
[ServiceArticle [articleId=17070, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=1], ServiceArticle [articleId=17071, productCode=1001, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=4], ServiceArticle [articleId=17070, productCode=1012, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=5], ServiceArticle [articleId=17070, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=1], ServiceArticle [articleId=17070, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=2]]

When I call the different microservice from my serviceImpl class I get the unsupported media type error

Code for serviceImpl class

```
private final String URI = "http://localhost:8082/admin/import/servicearticles";

@Override
public void insertData(List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticles) {
    logger.error("Inside insertData() in service");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    try {
            restTemplate.postForObject(URI, serviceArticles, ServiceArticle.class);
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        logger.error("ServiceArticleAdmin Service Unavailable.");
```

Below is the code for the controller in different micro-servie which maps to this call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/import/servicearticles", method =    RequestMethod.POST, consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle> addAll(@RequestBody List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticles) {

    List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticlesAdded = serviceArticleAdminService.addAll(serviceArticles);

    return new ResponseEntity(serviceArticlesAdded, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have added the below dependencies in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following bean definition in my servlet-context.xml

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- To convert JSON to Object and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

Please help me figure out where am I making a mistake.
Is there any way I can set response type as application/json when I am invoking
restTemplate.postForObject method

I verified using a REST client plugin it works there but not through my Java code. Please help.

Answer (score 23):

It seems that `Content-Type: application/json` header is missing.
Your method also returns a list of articles, not a single article, so the third argument in `postForObject` method is not correct.

The following code should do the job:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<List<ServiceArticle>> request = new HttpEntity<>(serviceArticles, headers);

ResponseEntity<List<ServiceArticle>> response = 
    restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.POST, request,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ServiceArticle>>() { });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Eien, I tried with this code, I am getting

     org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error

Comment: Yes it comes when restTemplate.exchange() is invoked which maps to the URI you mentioned

Comment: Stack Trace : at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
 at no.bring.priceengine.servicearticle.service.impl.ServiceArticleAdminServiceImpl.insertData(ServiceArticleAdminServiceImpl.java:65)

Comment: Check logs of the microservice that you invoke from your code. It seems that the error comes from there.

Comment: Control never enters that micro-service code.

Here is the method which should be invoked on restTemplate.exchange()

    @RequestMapping(value = "/import/servicearticles", method =    RequestMethod.POST, consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle> addAll(@RequestBody     List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticles) {

    List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticlesAdded =      serviceArticleAdminService.addAll(serviceArticles);
  
    return new ResponseEntity(serviceArticlesAdded, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

Comment: According to the stack trace, you receive 500 as the result of invocation of your another microservice. It means that something is wrong there. Anyway, to discover where the real problem is, more information is needed. Please, add logs of your both microservices at the moment of invocation to your question.

Comment: Yes @Eien, I get what your are trying to tell me, but no logs are printed for the microservice

Comment: WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 2):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/db")
public class EmployeeDataServerResource {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface ei;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public EmployeeTable addEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeTable      employeeTable) {

         ei.save(employeeTable);
         return employeeTable;
    }
}
```

This is my method of restController

```
public String onSave() {    
    try {
    EmployeeTable et = new EmployeeTable();
    et.setFirstName(firstName.getValue());
    et.setLastName(lastName.getValue());
    et.setEmail(email.getValue());
    et.setBirthdate(birthDate.getValue());
    et.setNumber(number.getValue());
    et.setPassword(pswd.getValue());
    et.setGender(rgroup.getValue());
    et.setCountry(select.getValue());
    et.setHobbiesLst(hobbies);

    String uri = "http://localhost:8090/db/add"; 
              
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity requestEntity=new HttpEntity(et, headers);

    ResponseEntity<EmployeeTable> addedRes = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,requestEntity,EmployeeTable.class);
    return ""+addedRes.getStatusCodeValue();
      
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(""+e.toString());
        return e.toString();
    }   
}
```

This is for add new employee in database using restController.
It worked for me...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code may solve both of your problems:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postnotewithclient",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postNote(@RequestBody  Note notes)
{
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<Note> entity = new  HttpEntity<Note>(notes,headers);
    return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/api/notes", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything was ok for post request but still unsupported exception was reported. After some tweaks to code, the real problem came into light and that was because of **Custom** **Deserializer** that I had for one of my fields

Debugging tip:
To make sure that your rest API is functioning fine. First try to receive the request as string and then try to convert that string using object mapper to required object.

Above tip in any way should not be used for production ready code . Hope this helps someone

Cheers!